# MDX: How to get MAX value and the hour when MAX value occurs for each day

Tags: grouping, mdx, ranking

I have a cube with defined Hour dimension and a column in the fact table named numberofoccurrances. How can I get the maximum number of occurrances and the hour when the value happened for each day. I have tried the following

```
SELECT [Measures].[numberofoccurrances] ON 0,
TOPCOUNT([Hour].[Hour].MEMBERS, 1, [Measures].[numberofoccurrances])
ON 1
FROM [all_measurements]
```

which finds the hour where the max value happened but the sums up all values for that hour and return wrong value.

Is there a way to get each hour with max value for a day in two columns?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use rank() and filter function. Take a look at the example below.

The query below list the internet sales for year -months

```
SELECT 
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS,
non empty ({[Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2011],[Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2012],[Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2013]},[Date].[Month of Year].[Month of Year])
ON ROWS 
FROM
[Adventure Works]
```

Results 
[image]

Now rank the months within years, and filter them first rand

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Monthly_Ranking_InternetSales] AS
RANK( [Date].[Month of Year].CurrentMember,
ORDER( [Date].[Month of Year].[Month of Year].Members , [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], BDESC)
) 
SELECT 
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS,
non empty
filter( ({[Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2011],[Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2012],[Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2013]},
ORDER  ([Date].[Month of Year].[Month of Year], [Measures].[Monthly_Ranking_InternetSales] , BASC ) 
),[Measures].[Monthly_Ranking_InternetSales] <2)
ON ROWS 
FROM
[Adventure Works]
```

Result

[image]

Comment: @ejfilip does it help?